# Using geometry nodes to use string to type using meshes from collection

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I'm looking to create a custom 3D typeface, for the first step I want to be able to type in a String input, with every letter in the alphabet corresponding to a mesh from a collection. Example:

In the geometry node modifier tab there's a string input where user can type text, let's use "HELLO WORLD".

In the 3D viewport you're able to see your text using instances of the collection. The letter H corresponds to a 3D letter H I've designed before within a collection, as for all the other letter (automatic spaces in between would be awesome).

I was looking into converting Strings to numbers (A = 0, B = 1, C = 2 etc.) but I've only seen String Length so far which is kinda useless for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey, the question title is very confusing.